# Bounded constraints for the CPLEX ILOG Optimization Studio

Tags: optimization, constraints, cplex, ilog

I want to have a constraint that has an upper and lower bound which is using the format lb<= expr <= ub

The constriant I want to translate is: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBSGw.png)

But how I have coded this is in this format:

> forall(k,i in G, j in chargingStationSet, m in numberOfEVs : i!=j && j!=k && k!=i){
> chargingStationTimeManagement:
> workHourLimit*(x[<i,j,m>] - 1)
> <=
> departureTime[<k,i>] +
> travelTime[<i,j>] +
> ((batteryCapacity[m] - remainingBatteryCapacity[<i,j,m>])/rechargingRate) - >departureTime[<i,j>]
> &&
> departureTime[<k,i>] +
> travelTime[<i,j>] +
> ((batteryCapacity[m] - remainingBatteryCapacity[<i,j,m>])/rechargingRate) - >departureTime[<i,j>]
> <=
> workHourLimit*(1- x[<i,j,m>] );
> }

Have I done this correctly here becuase the results are not what was expected?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of double inequality you should try 2 inequalities:

```
dvar int x;
dvar int y;
dvar int z;

subject to
{
  //x<=y<=z; // Not allowed
  x<=y;
  y<=z;
}
```